# Kong Error no Route matched with those values

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-lambda, amazon-eks, kong

currently I'm trying to add [aws-lambda](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/aws-lambda/) plugin to existing EKS which uses [Kong helmchart](https://github.com/Kong/charts/tree/main/charts/ingress) as an API gateway.

I already made a CRD for Kong plugin

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: aws-lambda-example
plugin: aws-lambda
config:
  aws_key: xxx
  aws_secret: xxxx
  aws_region: xxxx
  function_name: test-lambda
  forward_request_body: true
  forward_request_headers: true
  forward_request_uri: true
```

The project already had an ingress with the path of `/*`

```
annotations:
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.rule-path2: |
    [{"field":"path-pattern","pathPatternConfig":{"values":["/*"]}}]
spec:   
    rules:
    - host: xxxxx
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: kong-gw-ingress-gateway-proxy
                port:
                  number: 443
```

Because the lambda function only has some routes, I try to create another ingress with the following spec

```
annotations:
  konghq.com/plugins: aws-lambda-example <--- apply the Kong plugin
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.rule-path2: |
  [{"field":"path-pattern","pathPatternConfig":{"values":["/lambda"]}}]
spec:
  rules:
    - host: xxxxx
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /lambda
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: kong-gw-ingress-gateway-proxy
                port:
                  number: 443
```

I applied to the the cluster and got no error event

but when I try to call mydomain/lambda I get the following error.

> Kong Error no Route matched with those values.

the other routes(non aws-lambda routes) are still working file
why doesn't it receive the `/lambda` path and pass to the lambda function?